# Best way to find multiple values in an array

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table with a tags text array column.

I have tags in this array.

What is the best way to find if one or more tags is in the array ?

For exemple i want to find row with tag A and C in array {A,B,C,D} will match but not in {A,D,E}, i want to be able to find as many tags as the user want.

For the moment i use:

```
SELECT * FROM tarray WHERE ('tag1'=ANY(tags) AND 'tag4'=ANY(tags))
```

But it doesn't allow me to find easyly more than 2 tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contains operator for arrays is `<@`.

Positive test case

```
   postgresdb=> select ARRAY['tag1', 'tag4'] <@ ARRAY['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag4'] as result;
    -[ RECORD 1 ]
    result | t
```

negative test case

```
postgresdb=> select ARRAY['tag1', 'tag4'] <@ ARRAY['tag1', 'tag2'] as result;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
result | f
```

For your use-case, the query would be

```
SELECT * FROM tarray WHERE ARRAY['tag1', 'tag4'] <@ tags
```

Refer postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html) for more functions